# pivot table so users and their dates go to one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to go from something like this:

```
username    CourseID    DateTaken
mikeb       LST          5/9/2014
mikeb       SELAGENT001  4/4/2013
chrisp      AGT001       2/21/2012
chrisp      SELAGENT001  6/27/2011
```

to something like this:

```
Username    LST         SELAGENT001 AGT001
mikeb       5/9/2014    4/4/2013    
chrisp                  6/27/2011   2/21/2012
```

I tried missing around with crosstab, but since I'm dealing with dates I'm having a hard time. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's ANSI SQL solution to this, assuming you only have one row per `username, courseid` pair it would return expected results. Otherwise, it'd take the maximum `datetaken` value for each pair.

```
SELECT
  username,
  MAX(CASE WHEN courseid = 'LST' THEN datetaken END) AS lst,
  MAX(CASE WHEN courseid = 'SELAGENT001' THEN datetaken END) AS selagent001,
  MAX(CASE WHEN courseid = 'AGT001' THEN datetaken END) AS agt001
FROM t
GROUP BY username
```

If you want Postgres specific answer there is a [`crosstab()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) function in `tablefunc` module, but I personally always favor portable solutions over DBMS specific.

For reference you could also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/2095534)